# Cannot use JavaScriptLibrary with Selenium v3.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

In my Selenium automation framework, I use `JavaScriptLibrary` for clicking some elements.

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.JavascriptLibrary;

public class Utils{

 public static void click(WebDriver driver, WebElement element){
        JavascriptLibrary jsLib=new JavascriptLibrary();
        jsLib.callEmbeddedSelenium(driver, "triggerMouseEventAt", element, "click","0,0");
 }
}
```

The code was working fine when I was using `Selenium v2.53`. I recently upgraded Selenium client to `v3.0`. Since then eclipse showing the error,

```
The import com.thoughtworks cannot be resolved
```

and

```
JavascriptLibrary cannot be resolved to a type
```

Is javascript library not supported by v3.0?. Has it moved to another package ? or am missing some jar files?. 
Any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think the `com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven` package is part of the initial Selenium RC version. This has been removed from the Selenium 3.0 version.

I can't find good reference, but [the road to selenium 3.0 blog post](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/the-road-to-selenium-3/) has a comment with:

> For now you can simulate the effect by disallowing classes in the
>   com.thoughtworks.selenium package.

This leads me to think that you none of the com.thoughtworks.selenium packages will be available after the release.

I think you should either downgrade or use the [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This library emulates *Selenium v1* by injecting a script directly into the page. This version has been deprecated for a long time now and you shouldn't have to use it. *Selenium v3* is as much capable and does a better job at simulating a real user.

Take this Selenium v3 code which clicks an element at a location :

```java
new Actions(driver)
  .moveToElement(element, 1, 1)
  .click()
  .perform();
```

It will :

- Scroll the element into the view if it's not already.
- Ensure that the element is displayed and interractable.
- Emit the mouseover, mousemove, mousedown, mouseup, click events

On the other hand `triggerMouseEventAt` will only emit the click event, even if the element is not rendered.

If the idea is to use it as a workaround for something you didn't managed to do with Selenium 2/3, well you'll probably end-up with a test that doesn't really simulate a real user.

So using this library kind of defeat the purpose of testing.

But if you are still willing to use it, one way would be to inject the function with `executeScript`:

```java
public static void click(WebDriver driver, WebElement element){
    String script = "browserbot.triggerMouseEventAt(arguments[0], 'click', '0,0')";
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(JS_INJECTABLE + script, element);
}

// The code for JS_INJECTABLE :
// https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/com/thoughtworks/selenium/webdriven/injectableSelenium.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding the selenium-leg-rc library to my project with Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-leg-rc</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope it helps, best regards!
Hernán